# Issue with skipRedirectCallback auth0 config

Tags: angular, callback, auth0, okta, auth0-connection

I have recently migrated to auth0 in angular app, in my angular app i have other third-party integration available so when i perform authorization for those my application will redirect to the auth0 redirection URL.

[angular authModule config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ekNO.png)

i have added skipRedirectCallback config for skip other callbackurl, but when i build angular app for prod than skipRedirectCallback are not working

following is the main.js file which is generated after build

[value after angular build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50w81.png)

i have tried pass window.location.pathname === '/other-callbackurl' by function also but it is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.